# Create 3-way percentages table

Tags: stata, percentage

I would like to have a 3-way table displaying column or row percentages using three categorical variables. The command below gives the counts but I cannot find how to get percentages instead.

```
sysuse nlsw88

table married race collgrad, col

--------------------------------------------------------------------
          |                college graduate and race                
          | ---- not college grad ----    ------ college grad ------
  married | white  black  other  Total    white  black  other  Total
----------+---------------------------------------------------------
   single |   355    256      5    616      132     53      3    188
  married |   862    224     12  1,098      288     50      6    344
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I get percentages?

Comment: Percentages given `married`? `race`? `collgrad`? `everyone`? or 2 or 3 or 4 of those?

Comment: @nick Percentage given `collgrad`. Something like the % of white, single, not college grads is `355*100/(355+862)`. The percentage of single non college grads (irrespective of race) is `616*100/(606+1098)`. Something similar to the result of `bys collgrad: table married race, col` but in one table but not two tables like the one given by `bys`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer will show a miscellany of tricks. The downside is that I don't know an easy way to get exactly what you ask. The upside is that all these tricks are easy to understand and often useful.

Let's use your example, which is excellent for the purpose.

```
. sysuse nlsw88, clear 
(NLSW, 1988 extract)
```

**Tip #1 You can calculate a percent variable for yourself.** I focus on % single. In this data set `married` is binary, so I won't show the complementary percent. 
Once you have calculated it, you can (a) rely on the fact that it is constant within the groups you used to define it (b) tabulate it directly. I find that `tabdisp` is underrated by users. It's billed as a programmer's command, but it is not difficult to use at all. `tabdisp` lets you set a display format on the fly; it does no harm and might be useful for other commands to assign one directly using `format`.

```
. egen pcsingle = mean(100 * (1 - married)), by(collgrad race)

. tabdisp collgrad race, c(pcsingle) format(%2.1f)

--------------------------------------
                 |        race        
college graduate | white  black  other
-----------------+--------------------
not college grad |  29.2   53.3   29.4
    college grad |  31.4   51.5   33.3
--------------------------------------

. format pcsingle %2.1f
```

**Tip #2 A user-written command `groups` offers different flexibility.** `groups` can be installed from SSC (strictly, *must* be installed before you can use it). It's a wrapper for various kinds of tables, but using `list` as a display engine.

```
. * do this installation just once 
. ssc inst groups 

. groups collgrad race pcsingle 

  +-------------------------------------------------------+
  |         collgrad    race   pcsingle   Freq.   Percent |
  |-------------------------------------------------------|
  | not college grad   white       29.2    1217     54.19 |
  | not college grad   black       53.3     480     21.37 |
  | not college grad   other       29.4      17      0.76 |
  |     college grad   white       31.4     420     18.70 |
  |     college grad   black       51.5     103      4.59 |
  |-------------------------------------------------------|
  |     college grad   other       33.3       9      0.40 |
  +-------------------------------------------------------+
```

We can improve on that. We can set up better header text using characteristics. (In practice, these can be less constrained than variable names but often need to be shorter than variable labels.) We can use separators by calling up standard `list` options.

```
. char pcsingle[varname] "% single"

. char collgrad[varname] "college?"

. groups collgrad race pcsingle , subvarname sepby(collgrad) 

  +-------------------------------------------------------+
  |         college?    race   % single   Freq.   Percent |
  |-------------------------------------------------------|
  | not college grad   white       29.2    1217     54.19 |
  | not college grad   black       53.3     480     21.37 |
  | not college grad   other       29.4      17      0.76 |
  |-------------------------------------------------------|
  |     college grad   white       31.4     420     18.70 |
  |     college grad   black       51.5     103      4.59 |
  |     college grad   other       33.3       9      0.40 |
  +-------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Tip #3 Wire display formats into a variable by making a string equivalent.** I don't illustrate this fully, but I often use it when I want to combine a display of counts with numerical results with decimal places in `tabdisp`. `format(%2.1f)` and `format(%3.2f)` might do fine for most variables (and incidentally the important detail is the number of decimal places) but they would lead to a display of a count of 42 as 42.0 or 42.00, which would look pretty silly. The `format()` option of `tabdisp` does not reach into the string and change the contents; it doesn't even know what the string variable contains or where it came from. So, strings just get shown by `tabdisp` as they come, which is what you want.

```
. gen s_pcsingle = string(pcsingle, "%2.1f") 

. char s_pcsingle[varname] "% single"
```

`groups` has an option to save what is tabulated as a fresh dataset.

**Tip #4 To have a total category, temporarily double up the data.** The clone of the original is relabelled as a Total category. You may need to do some extra calculations, but nothing there amounts to rocket science: a smart high school student could figure it out. Here a concrete example for line-by-line study beats lengthy explanations.

```
. preserve 

. local Np1 = _N + 1 

. expand 2 
(2,246 observations created)

. replace race = 4 in `Np1'/L 
(2,246 real changes made)

. label def racelbl 4 "Total", modify  

. drop pcsingle 

. egen pcsingle = mean(100 * (1 - married)), by(collgrad race)

. char pcsingle[varname] "% single"

. format pcsingle %2.1f 

. gen istotal = race == 4 

. bysort collgrad istotal: gen total = _N 

. * for percents of the global total, we need to correct for doubling up     
. scalar alltotal = _N/2 

. * the table shows percents for college & race | collgrad and for collgrad | total 
. bysort collgrad race : gen pc = 100 * cond(istotal, total/alltotal, _N/total)  
. format pc %2.1f
. char pc[varname] "Percent" 

. groups collgrad race pcsingle pc , show(f) subvarname sepby(collgrad istotal) 

  +-------------------------------------------------------+
  |         college?    race   % single   Percent   Freq. |
  |-------------------------------------------------------|
  | not college grad   white       29.2      71.0    1217 |
  | not college grad   black       53.3      28.0     480 |
  | not college grad   other       29.4       1.0      17 |
  |-------------------------------------------------------|
  | not college grad   Total       35.9      76.3    1714 |
  |-------------------------------------------------------|
  |     college grad   white       31.4      78.9     420 |
  |     college grad   black       51.5      19.4     103 |
  |     college grad   other       33.3       1.7       9 |
  |-------------------------------------------------------|
  |     college grad   Total       35.3      23.7     532 |
  +-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Note the extra trick of using a variable not shown explicitly to add separator lines.

Comment: Works well and sure does not involve rocket science. Would be nice to have it wrapped up in a single function call. Would be a plus to have also the chi-square statistics. eg. association between race and married given collgrad

Comment: When you say function, you mean command. But your comment underscores the key difficulty. Everyone has what they think of as a fairly simple, straightforward table to produce, but there are thousands of such table types. A general command to make any kind of table is the asymptote here. The syntax would be pages and pages long and the documentation an entire manual volume. Or you can write a program yourself to create the tables you want with one syntax. That's how each program got started, and this is a forum for professional and enthusiast programmers!